# Sorcerer Multiclass learning spells

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, sorcerer

So i am playing in a high level game where i am playing a 13th level Storm sorcerer multiclassed with a 2nd level Tempest Cleric. At the end of the last session we levelled up and I am taking a 14th level in Sorcerer.

Now, as a 16th level caster, I have 8th level spell slots. Under “Spells known of 1st level and higher” it says that

> > ... you learn more sorcerer spells of your choice. Each of these spells must be of a level for which you have spell slots

Does this mean that i can choose 8th level sorcerer spells? Has this been clarified anywhere?

I am aware of the discussions around wizards copying in higher level spells but the argument there seems to resolve around the fact that they could probably copy them into their book, but would be unable to prepare them. Sorcerers do not prepare spells and so it is a different question. 
Many thanks guys!

Comment: The reason this was closed as a dupe is because this question is answered by the quote "You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class" in the other question.  That quote provides the same answer here.

Comment: Also because we really don't need a separate question for every different possible multiclass combination.